# javascript select box function: filter based on option value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript function which will filter table rows based on a select box option value which is already working, Now i am trying to achieve a function which will filter rows based on the select box value + anytext after that value. Btw i am a novice with javascript.

my selectbox code:

```
        <select name="filterdivision" id="filterdivision">
        <option selected="selected" value="">Select Division</option>
        <option value="Metals and Minerals">Metals and Minerals</option>
        <option value="Industrial">Industrial</option>
        <option value="Rail">Rail</option>
        <option value="Corporate">Corporate</option>
        <option value="GSC">GSC</option>
        </select>
```

My table html

```
        <table class="winner-data" width="100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th class="sort" data-sort="name">Heading 1</th>
        <th class="sort" data-sort="category">Heading 2</th>
        <th class="sort" data-sort="division">Division/Region</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="list">
        <tr>
        <td class="name">IKG Mexico Management Team</td>
        <td class="category">Customer</td>
        <td class="division">Industrial</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="name">Tubarão Brazil Site</td>
        <td class="category">Customer</td>
        <td class="division">Metals and Minerals</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="name">Euridice Mason</td>
        <td class="category">Customer</td>
        <td class="division">Metals and Minerals</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="name">Brazil Tax Team</td>
        <td class="category">Customer</td>
        <td class="division">Metals and Minerals Brazil</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="name">M&amp;M Bid and Contract Team</td>
        <td class="category">Customer</td>
        <td class="division">Metals and Minerals Central</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

My Javascript:

```
$('#filtercategory').change(function () {
var selection = this.value;

if($(this).val()!==""){
    // filter items in the list
    userList.filter(function (item) {
        return (item.values().category == selection);
    });     
}else{
    userList.filter();
    return false;
}

});
```

The current function is filtering division: for example it will filter "Metals and Minerals" so i want it to filter "Metals and Minerals + anything"

Comment: `var selection =this.value + anything`

Comment: @George Bailey what I mean by "anything" here is it should filter "Metals and Minerals Brazil"  and "Metals and Minerals Central" as well. Hope i am clear with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's currently filtering such that the category (loosely) equals the selection:

```
return (item.values().category == selection);
```

If you want to filter by if the *division* *includes* the selection, then use the `.includes` string method:

```
return item.values().division.toLowerCase().includes(selection.toLowerCase());
```

Or if you don't want to test for `toLowerCase`:

```
return item.values().division.includes(selection);
```

You may need a polyfill if you want to support old browsers.

Comment: Hi, i will try that, seems like an answer, so i am thinking if i can have something like:
    return item.values().category.includes(selection + a-zcharecters);
can you give me a proper code for that?

Comment: I don't understand the difference between `.includes` and what you're referring to. If you want, you could return a test to see of the `category` passes a regular expression test based on the `selection`.

Comment: return item.values().category.includes(selection); did not work it cleared all table rows

Comment: You might need to convert both to lower case first, see edit.

Comment: Could you post a live example of your code so the issue can be replicated? Need to know the context of `userList` to figure out what's going on

Comment: hi 

return (item.values().division.includes (selection)); it actual worked, sorry for the mistake i was checking ".category" select box inestead fo .division box. pleas add it in the code i will mark it as an answer. you just saved my day.

Comment: return (item.values().division.includes (selection)); could you please edit to this so that i can upvote and mark it as an answer

Comment: A `toLowerCase` conversion is almost always a good idea in this situation, but I put in a line without it if you want.